# confused about numpy.c_ document and sample code

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning

I read the document about numpy.c_ many times but still confused. It is said -- "Translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis." in the following document. Could anyone clarify in the example below, what is slice objects, and what is 2nd axis? I see they are all one dimension and confused where the 2nd axis coming from.

Using Python 2.7 on Windows.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#numpy.c_

```
>>> np.c_[np.array([[1,2,3]]), 0, 0, np.array([[4,5,6]])]
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 15):

`np.c_` is another way of doing array concatenate

```
In [701]: np.c_[np.array([[1,2,3]]), 0, 0, np.array([[4,5,6]])]
Out[701]: array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])

In [702]: np.concatenate([np.array([[1,2,3]]), [[0]], [[0]], np.array([[4,5,6]])], 
     axis=1)
Out[702]: array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```

The output shape is (1,8) in both cases; the concatenation was on axis=1, the 2nd axis.

`c_` took care of expanding the dimensions of the `0` to `np.array([[0]])`, the 2d (1,1) needed to concatenate.

`np.c_` (and `np.r_`) is actually a class object with a `__getitem__` method, so it works with the `[]` syntax.  The `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` source file is instructive reading.

Note that the `row` version works with the : slice syntax, producing a 1d (8,) array (same numbers, but in 1d)

```
In [706]: np.r_[1:4,0,0,4:7]
Out[706]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
In [708]: np.concatenate((np.arange(4),[0],[0],np.arange(4,7)))
Out[708]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
In [710]: np.hstack((np.arange(4),0,0,np.arange(4,7)))
Out[710]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
```

`np.c_` is a convenience, but not something you are required to understand.  I think being able to work with `concatenate` directly is more useful.  It forces you to think explicitly about the dimensions of the inputs.

`[[1,2,3]]` is actually a list - a list containing one list.  `np.array([[1,2,3]])` is a 2d array with shape (1,3).  `np.arange(1,4)` produces a (3,) array with the same numbers.  `np.arange(1,4)[None,:]` makes it a (1,3) array.

`slice(1,4)` is a slice object.  `np.r_` and `np.c_` can turn a slice object into a array - by actually using `np.arange`.

```
In [713]: slice(1,4)
Out[713]: slice(1, 4, None)
In [714]: np.r_[slice(1,4)]
Out[714]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [715]: np.c_[slice(1,4)]   # (3,1) array
Out[715]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [716]: np.c_[1:4]   # equivalent with the : notation
Out[716]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

And to get back to the original example (which might not be the best):

```
In [722]: np.c_[[np.r_[1:4]],0,0,[np.r_[4:7]]]
Out[722]: array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```

==========

```
In [731]: np.c_[np.ones((5,3)),np.random.randn(5,10)].shape
Out[731]: (5, 13)
```

For `np.c_` the 1st dimension of both needs to match.

In the `learn` example, `n_samples` is the 1st dim of `X` (rows), and the `randn` also needs to have that many rows.

```
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]
```

`np.concatenate([(X, randn(n_samples...)], axis=1)` should work just as well here.  A little wordier, but functionally the same.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, nice reply and vote up. Actually my confusion is coming from this sample, refer to this line `X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]`, actually X's shape is 150 * 4,  but `random_state.randn` will generate some scalar random numbers falls into normal distribution, how they be concatenated together, I think in order to concatenate with X, we need something shape of 150 * some_number_of_columns, correct? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings

Comment: Right, `n_samples` is the 1st dimension of `X`, so they will match on the right dimension.  The number of columns of `X` and `randn` can differ.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, I think X is 150 * 4 shape, how could `random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)` output 150 * 4 shape? I know `n_samples` is 150, but where did the 4 parts coming from?

Comment: Careful, 150 * 4 shape?  Is that (150*4,) or (150,4)?  1d or 2?  In `200*n_features` they mean multiplication.  The first dimension of `X` is `n_samples`.  That's how `n_samples` is defined.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, debugged and it seems `random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)` could provide (150, 800) shape? A bit confused, in my experience with `random_state.randn`, it only accept one parameter, what does the 2nd parameter mean for `random_state.randn`? I do not find it accept another parameter from `random_state.randn`s numpy document page.