# Numpy: Subtract 2 numpy arrays row wise

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays a and b as below:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2))
Out[124]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8],
       [0, 4]])
b = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2))
Out[125]: 
array([[5, 9],
       [2, 4]])
```

I want to subtract each row in b from each row in a and the desired output is of shape(3,2,2):

```
array([[[-5, -7],        [-2, -2]],

       [[ 1, -1],        [ 4,  4]],

       [[-5, -5],        [-2,  0]]])
```

I can do this using:

```
print(np.c_[(a - b[0]),(a - b[1])].reshape(3,2,2))
```

But I need a fully vectorized solution or a built in numpy function to do this.

Comment: What I mean by fully vectorized solution(factorized is a typo before) is I don't want to reference array b by its index like b[i] because the number of rows in this array can change and I want to have a solution which will always output an array of shape (3,len(b),2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `np.newaxis` (which is just an alias for None) to add a singleton dimension to a, and let broadcasting do the rest:

```
In [45]: a[:, np.newaxis] - b
Out[45]: 
array([[[-5, -7],
        [-2, -2]],

       [[ 1, -1],
        [ 4,  4]],

       [[-5, -5],
        [-2,  0]]])
```

Comment: this is about 40% faster than my best solution.  could you better explain what is happening here?  its a bit abstract

Comment: This is very memory inefficient for large arrays; I want to subtract a `5000 x 3078` array from a `500 x 3078` array and this would take `500 * 3072 * 5000 * 8 / 1e9 = 61.44` gigabytes.

Comment: This really is neat answer. We even can substract vector with list of scalar, resulting in matrix: `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])`, `b = np.array([1,2,3])`, `a[:, np.newaxis]-b`. Resulting in shape `(6,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can shave a little time off using np.subtract(), and a good bit more using np.concatenate()

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):

    a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2))
    b = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2))
    c = np.c_[(a - b[0]),(a - b[1])].reshape(3,2,2)

print time.time() - start

start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):

    a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2))
    b = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2))
    #c = np.c_[(a - b[0]),(a - b[1])].reshape(3,2,2)
    c = np.c_[np.subtract(a,b[0]),np.subtract(a,b[1])].reshape(3,2,2)

print time.time() - start

start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):

    a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2))
    b = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2))
    #c = np.c_[(a - b[0]),(a - b[1])].reshape(3,2,2)
    c = np.concatenate([np.subtract(a,b[0]),np.subtract(a,b[1])],axis=1).reshape(3,2,2)

print time.time() - start

>>>

3.14023900032
3.00368094444
1.16146492958
```

reference:

[confused about numpy.c_ document and sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136730/confused-about-numpy-c-document-and-sample-code)

> np.c_ is another way of doing array concatenate

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please see my comments in the question.

Comment: ah I see, that adds a twist. I wasn't sure what you meant by factorized in the original op, will ponder; see if I can conjure something. nonetheless reduced cpu load is always a plus

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what means a fully factorized solution, but may be this will help:

```
np.append(a, a, axis=1).reshape(3, 2, 2) - b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please see my comments in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the doc on *broadcasting*, it says:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> ```
> they are equal, or
> one of them is 1
> ```

Back to your case, you want result to be of shape `(3, 2, 2)`, following these rules, you have to play around with your dimensions.
Here's now the code to do it:

```
In [1]: a_ = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)

In [2]: b_ = np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)

In [3]: c = a_ - b_

In [4]: c
Out[4]: 
array([[[-5, -7],
        [ 1, -1],
        [-5, -5]],

       [[-2, -2],
        [ 4,  4],
        [-2,  0]]])

In [5]: result = c.swapaxes(1, 0)

In [6]: result
Out[6]: 
array([[[-5, -7],
        [-2, -2]],

       [[ 1, -1],
        [ 4,  4]],

       [[-5, -5],
        [-2,  0]]])

In [7]: result.shape
Out[7]: (3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer still work if say, A and B had more than two columns?